# RewriteRules repeating part of the match

Tags: apache, subdomain, mod-rewrite

What I'm trying to achieve is trying to match both the subdomain and the full path  in order to redirect to a version without www. in front of it. To do so I use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+).mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [C]
RewriteRule ^www\.(.+)\.mydomain\.com/(.*)$ http://$1.mydomain.com/$2 [R=permanent,L]
```

This works ok if I request something like:

```
www.me.mydomain.com/page
```

It redirects to:

```
me.mydomain.com/page
```

However, if I enter:

```
www.me.mydomain.com/page/other
```

It redirects to:

```
me.mydomain.com/page/other/other
```

It always repeats the part after the first slash. I can't find out what is causing the repetition.  ( I actually encountered the problem in a more complex case, but this was the most simple version I could reproduce it with)

Comment: Ok, I actually found a solution that avoids the problem by using:
   RewriteRule ^www\.(.+)\.mydomain\.com/(.*)$ http://$1.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}
Still curious though where the repetition comes from

Comment: Would you be kind and answer your question + accept it unless if you are hoping for alternative answers..